# Does Kana Akatsuki have any published works other than Violet Evergarden?

Tags: violet-evergarden

I have found very little information online about Kana Akatsuki, the author of the original light novel *Violet Evergarden*, and I can find nothing about any other works by her. Is this her only published work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find more information if you search by their  name in Japanese 暁佳奈.

They don't have any other works listed on their [goodreads author profile](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/15286681._).

There is an interview with the author on [Kyoto Animation's website](http://www.kyotoanimation.co.jp/kyoani_award/interview/). At the top of the page it states that this was their debut work:

> 第5回京都アニメーション大賞小説部門で同賞初の大賞を受賞し、『ヴァイオレット・エヴァーガーデン』で**デビュー。**

The last word [デビュー means debut.](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%83%87%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC)

The interview additionally states that it took 6 months to create Violet Evergarden and that it was made specifically for the Kyoto Animation award, because Kana Akatsuki loved Clannad: After Story anime which came from their studio.

> **――なぜ京都アニメーション大賞に応募しようと思われたのですか？**
>
> アニメ「CLANNAD 〜AFTER STORY〜」が大好きで、あの作品を作られた会社さんだからです。頭の中の映像を文字に起こすように書いていますので、本当に映像になったら面白いと思いました。 京都アニメーションさんで実現したら素敵だろうな、と夢見ました。
>
> ――**京アニ大賞応募時、『ヴァイオレット・エヴァーガーデン』の執筆にはどれくらい時間をかけられたのでしょうか。**
>
> 恐らく半年くらいだと思われます。寒い時期にカーディガンをずるずる引きずってお湯を沸かし紅茶を飲みながら書いていた記憶があります。北海道はいつも寒いので記憶が曖昧です。

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。 This is a good, solid answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think Violet Evergarden was Kana Akatsuki's Debut work.

Violet Evergarden was written for one of Kyoto Animation's competitions, and it won the grand prize (2014); hence the Anime adaptation.

Comment: I’m afraid this answer is not very useful. The fact that the light novel won the 2014 grand prize is easily found. The claim that it was written specifically *for* the competition is unsourced and I cannot confirm it; in any case it does not seem relevant to the question. The claim that it was her debut work is also unsourced; I cannot confirm it (or I would not have had to post this question); and you seem uncertain about it. So I’m pretty much as much in the dark as I was before.

Comment: @TomZych Apologies for the subpar answer, didn't have time to do my research; so I left an answer planning on adding onto it later. But I guess that is no longer needed; as the accepted answer looks good. Cheers~